# Oracle aggregate functions slows query down massively

Tags: oracle, performance, aggregate

I have a table with ~12M rows of data in it. Here is the table structure:

```
SYSTEM_ID
BATCH_ID
MEASUREMENT_INDEX,
PARAMETER_ONE,
PARAMETER_TWO
```

The primary key is made up of the first three columns. I also have an index on `SYSTEM_ID ASC`, `BATCH_ID ASC`.

If I do the following query:

```
SELECT PARAMETER_ONE 
  FROM RESULTS_TABLE 
 WHERE SYSTEM_ID=1 
   AND BATCH_ID=100;
```

The results come back in about 0.002 seconds.

However, when I try to do ANY aggregate function, e.g. `SUM`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `STDDEV`, the query time raises to around 400 seconds! I have tried various permutations of this query e.g.:

```
SELECT AVG(PARAMETER_ONE) 
  FROM ( SELECT PARAMETER_ONE 
           FROM RESULTS_TABLE 
          WHERE SYSTEM_ID=1 
            AND BATCH_ID=100
        );
```

And:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       AVG(PARAMETER_ONE) over (partition by system_id, batch_id)
 FROM RESULTS_TABLE
WHERE SYSTEM_ID = 123
  AND BATCH_ID = 10;
```

Neither of these seems to make a difference. Has anyone else had this problem??

===========================

## MORE DETAILS

The explain plan for the aggregate function query is:

```
Plan hash value: 2759933517

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                              |     1 |    32 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                              |     1 |    32 |            |          |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RESULTS_DATA                 |     1 |    32 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | RESULTS_DATA_INDEX1          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

---

### Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

3 - access("SYSTEM_ID"='123' AND "BATCH_ID"='10')

The explain plan for just a simple select is:

```
Plan hash value: 1958859493

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                              |     1 |    32 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RESULTS_DATA                 |     1 |    32 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | RESULTS_DATA_INDEX1          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("SYSTEM_ID"='123' AND "BATCH_ID"='10')
```

What is surprising is that the explain plan for both seems to claim that it takes only 1 second to carry out that query, but it definitely does not, either in SQL Developer or SQL Plus...

## ==================================================

### UPDATE

Here is the autotrace of the query with aggregate function as requested:

```
SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain statistics
SQL> SELECT avg(tail_intensity) FROM RESULTS_DATA WHERE SYSTEM_ID = '12
3' AND BATCH_ID = '10';


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2759933517

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------

| Id  | Operation                    | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                              |     1 | 32    |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |

|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                              |     1 | 32    |            |          |

|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| RESULTS_DATA                 |     1 | 32    |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |

|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | RESULTS_DATA_INDEX1          |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("SYSTEM_ID"='123' AND "BATCH_ID"='10')


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
     437569  consistent gets
     437129  physical reads
          0  redo size
        433  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        416  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          1  rows processed
```

Comment: What are the query plans?  How many rows does the first query return?  Is 0.002 seconds the time to return the first row?  Or the time to return the last row?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the plans (so that you can format them so that they are readable).  Don't try to post the plans in the comments.

Comment: Hi Justin, I've now edited the post to contain the explain plans. The simple query without AVG() returns 101 rows, and it takes 0.002 seconds to return all of them.

Comment: Can you generate and post a complete plan using the `DBMS_XPLAN` package?  In particular, we're going to want to see columns for things like cardinality, cost, and estimated time as well as the filter predicates.

Comment: I've just updated the post to include the results from SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY). Is that sufficient?

Comment: @user1578653 can you post `autotrace` for both queries also?

Comment: What happens when you do an autotrace rather than an explain (you can do that with SQL Developer (F6), or `set autotrace traceonly explain statistics` and run the queries)? Are your stats accurate?

Comment: I've added the results of autotrace - it looks the same as the explain plan to me...Again it claims to have taken only 1 second, but it took well over 5 minutes for the autotrace to finish!

Comment: `437129  physical reads` is 3Gb of disk IO (assuming 8k block size). Stats must be way out.

Comment: When you say the first query (non-aggregate) returns in 0.002 seconds, do you mean the first few rows are populated in SQL Developer? I ask, because that's completely different to getting the full resultset.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the reply. What stats do you refer to? And how can I fix this issue? Also, I have just noticed something strange. If I select count(*) from results_data where system_id='123' and batch_id='10' I get the number 101. If I then try just "select paramater_one from results_data where system_id='123' and batch_id='10'" SQL developer returns the first 100 rows and then hangs when I try to see the 101st record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all your input - I seem to have solved it. I recalculated table statistics using:

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(OWNNAME=>USER,TABNAME=>'RESULTS
_DATA');
```

After this, the queries worked fine.